# Uploadify won't upload files to my php script!

Tags: php, javascript, upload, flash

I'm trying to get uploadify to send it's files to a php script but it comes back blank every time... i'm totally confused as sometimes it won't even attempt to upload the files.

Form:

```
<form action="upload.php?1" method="post" id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' name='uploadBox' id='uploadBox' /><br/>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="{Upload}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        // makes the flash uploader work
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#uploadBox').uploadify ({
            'uploader'  : 'uploader.swf?PHPSESSID=4aa17bc8a50f8265ee27ec5fb469d7e5',
            'script'    : 'upload.ajax.php?PHPSESSID=4aa17bc8a50f8265ee27ec5fb469d7e5',
            'cancelImg' : 'cancel.png',
            'auto'      : false,
            'sizeLimit' : '8388608',
            'buttonText' : "Browse",
            'multi'     : true,
            'fileExt'   : "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png",
            'scriptData': {'album':"1", "session":"4aa17bc8a50f8265ee27ec5fb469d7e5"},
            onError : function(event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj){ alert("ERROR"); console.log(errorObj); }
            });
            $("#uploadForm .button").click(function(){
                $("#uploadBox").uploadifyUpload();
                console.log("uploading...");
                return false;
            });
            console.log("attached");
        });
        </script>
</form>
```

And this is the upload.ajax.php file:
Notes on it: it requires the session to be working for it to work and add_to_album does all the thumbnail work and stuff

```
<?php
// upload photos via background flash thingy mobob
include "../../functions.php"; start($_REQUEST['PHPSESSID']);
include "../../inc/photo.php";
// we need to upload this file we've got to the normal stuff we use :D
if(!is_logged_in()){
    echo "0";
    exit;
}
$fail = false;
foreach($_FILES as $file){
    if(add_to_album($file['tmp_name'], $_REQUEST['album']) == false)
        $fail = true;
}
echo "upload has finished";
if($fail == true)
    echo "0";
else
    echo "1";
```

Comment: Have you checked the web log for errors?  A blank page is indicative of a fatal error, which will probably be logged in your web server log.

Comment: what are the permissions on the directory you are uploading to?

Comment: I've had Console.app open with the log and it comes up in the access log but nothing in the error log. And the function that stores the file has permissions set... it's fully tested and works... just not with Flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHA! Just realized the major problem with it. The start() function was looking for a langauge, failed and told the script to die... so it wouldn't work

BAM! Everything lit up and it worked :D

YAY :D

Answer (score 0):

What is the foreach for? If you input filename is called uploadBox check for $_FILES['uploadBox ']['tmp_name'].

Comment: It's for my script to catch anything... it doesn't want to upload anything... it's very confusing